# Calculate how many pixels=1 in a 3*3 kernel based on GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap, image-encoding

Now, I have a cropland map. It's only one band, 1=cropland,0=Non-cropland.
So how to calculate how many pixels=1 in a 3*3 kernel?
and then get a map of contain the numbers.

eg:

```
[1,0,1],  
[1,0,1],  
[1,1,0]
```

stand for 9 pixels. how to get the number of '1' =6?

Comment: Start by looking at the documentation ([Image Neighborhoods](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_reduce_neighborhood), [ee.Kernel.square](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-kernel-square) and  [ee.Reducer.sum](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-reducer-sum)) then edit your question and provide a code attempt .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just sum it.
If you sum of 3x3 kernel, you will have how many ones you have.

Comment: Cool ‍ You are amazing, I will continue to follow your blog